# fragment of code from the Clang documentation page

Tags: c++, c, clang

In the [Clang documentation page](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/alpha_checks.html#cplusplus_alpha_checkers) there is a fragment of following code:

```
struct seven_words {
  int c[7];
};

void test() {
  struct seven_words a, *p;
  p = &a;
  p[0] = a;
  p[1] = a;
  p[2] = a; // warn
}
```

Why the checker warns only at the line with accesing to p[2] whereas there is a segmentation fault on line `p[1] = a;`. Is it a limit of the checker or there is something that I don't understand?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing it? Most likely it is just a typo.

Comment: I’d say it’s either a bug in the checker (which is labelled as alpha) or in the documentation. As @VTT suggests, the documentation is more likely.

Comment: Either way, it would be more productive to post on their bug tracker than on SO.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to reproduce it.The checker doesn't produce any warning even about line p[2] = a;

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is incorrect. (Or, if it correctly documents the behavior of the analyzer, the analyzer is deficient because it fails to detect a clear problem.)